# Software does not work properly after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, software-center, 16.04

The title says already everything.
I upgraded without problems from 15.10 to 16.04 LTS, the icon for Ubuntu Software remained the same, if i open it i get the new GNOME version, but when i search for some apps (like GIMP, or VLC Player) i get "no application found".

Strange, isn't it ?

Comment: Nothing strange in Ubuntu new verion bugs. There hasn't been an update that is not bugged in some way or another. In my case I don't see any software at all. I still have software center tough, which is strange by itself also.

Comment: yes, i still have software center too

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy gimp vlc`?

Comment: gimp:
  Installed: 2.8.16-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.8.16-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2.8.16-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status



vlc:
  Installed: 2.2.2-5
  Candidate: 2.2.2-5
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.2-5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I got it working by changing the language of the system into English. I think the problem was that the programme descriptions are not available in my language.

Comment: english is already the language of the system